# Prefactor to amplitude for massless fermions/massive bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

I was reviewing some of my old notes and found this formula for a matrix elements between two states:

$$
<f|S|i>= \delta_{fi} + [(2\pi)^4 \delta^4(P_f - P_i) \prod_{ext. fermion}\left(\frac{m}{VE} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \prod_{ext. boson}\left(\frac{1}{2V\omega} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}]\mathcal{M}_{fi}
$$

But this formula seems to me to imply massive fermions and massless boson (which makes sense since it was derived in an introductory setting, only taking QED into account). What factors would appear if we included massive bosons ($W^\pm$, $Z$) or massless fermions (ie: neutrinos)? Should the sums simply be iterated over external massless/massive particles?